# console message JavaScript with green checkmark

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, console.log

I was wondering if the was a possibility to have a green checkmark in your console just like console.warn has the yellow warning sign and console.error has the red error sign.

I have searched on the internet if there already was a function like that, but I couldn't find it. Now I'm looking for a way to put an icon before a `console.log` message.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly is. You can use CSS in Chrome:

```
console.log("%c hi", "background: url(path/to/your/icon.png) 0 0 no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;");
```

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject_object):

> Dev Tools supports the following format specifiers:
>
> %c    Formats the output string according to CSS styles you provide.

**Caveat:**

The console [doesn't support background-repeat](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352140) for some odd reason. So you'd be better either adding some padding to your icon, or else moving the icon to the right-hand side:

```
console.log("hi %c", "background: url(path/to/your/icon.png) 0 0 no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;");
```