# Stylized console logging

Tags: javascript, console

When I'm on Facebook and have the console open, I see this image below. How do they do this?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687459/console-message-javascript-with-green-checkmark. Or at least I'd assume this is how it's done.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just like in Firebug you can use `%c` to style console log output. Look how we could implement Facebook's example:

```
console.log("%cStop!", "color: red; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 4.5em; font-weight: bolder; text-shadow: #000 1px 1px;");
```

[image: Facebook's example]

Since it supports CSS properties, we can even "draw" images in there:

```js
(function(url) {
  // Create a new `Image` instance
  var image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    // Inside here we already have the dimensions of the loaded image
    var style = [
      // Hacky way of forcing image's viewport using `font-size` and `line-height`
      'font-size: 1px;',
      'line-height: ' + this.height + 'px;',

      // Hacky way of forcing a middle/center anchor point for the image
      'padding: ' + this.height * .5 + 'px ' + this.width * .5 + 'px;',

      // Set image dimensions
      'background-size: ' + this.width + 'px ' + this.height + 'px;',

      // Set image URL
      'background: url('+ url +');'
     ].join(' ');

     // notice the space after %c
     console.log('%c ', style);
  };

  // Actually loads the image
  image.src = url;
})('https://i.cloudup.com/Zqeq2GhGjt-3000x3000.jpeg');
```

[image: Displaying an image on console log]

Comment: Works in Chrome 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)

Comment: +1 for the background-image example. Any idea why it's also logging 'undefined'? I can't seem to get rid of that.

Comment: @Olivier  try doing -> `'%c '`, notice the space.  I looks like because you are not rendering any text, there is nothing for it to style.

Comment: Example will log the image to console twice, not quite sure why. Using chromium 71

Comment: Nice, it work. In my case i have 2 image (repeated). Any idea why?

Comment: For those getting repeating, try this: `background: no-repeat url(${url})`

Comment: This stopped working, any idea why ?

Comment: @Wonay use data URI instead of image URL

Answer (score 3):

For those who have two images, repeated, add background no-repeat as @BayyMekenique says but also change this line:

`code` 'line-height: ' + this.height + 'px;', `code`

to this:

`code` 'line-height: ' + this.height % 2 + 'px;', `code`

[image]

Comment: This stopped working, any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped this solution in a nice library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-log-img

It can also display images from a Canvas or Image element, ImageBitmap and more!