# google chrome console, print image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

About year ago i created a plugin to enhance console logs, main idea was to print images in console, so for example You could add some icons or glyphs.

It was working pretty nice, i saw that there is many of those available online right now. The problem is that none of them are working atm.

I noticed it after last chrome update i think. currently i have version `49.0.2623.112`.

All of those plugins including mine works in the same way:

```
console.log("%c" + dim.string, dim.style + "background: url(" + url + "); background-size: " + (this.width * scale) + "px " + (this.height * scale) + "px; color: transparent;");
```

For example this one: [plugin link on github](https://github.com/adriancooney/console.image/blob/master/console.image.js)

Does anyone know how we can print images in console in newer versions of chrome ?

Comment: In the lastest documentation, therre's nothing new about displaying images in the console: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-write#string-substitution-and-formatting

Comment: yes but something has happened that its not possible anymore to print them.

Comment: you can make a better effort with a question title

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try a code example with console F12:

```js
console.log('%c ', 'font-size:400px; background:url(https://pics.me.me/codeit-google-until-youfinda-stackoverflow-answerwith-code-to-copy-paste-34126823.png) no-repeat;');
```

Comment: It may be useful add `backdround-size: contain;` so the image is fully shown.

Comment: @AurelianoFarSuau g -> d typo

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore in Chrome 101

Answer (score 10):

I've been searching for a while for one that can print out the whole image without cutting it, and make it resizeable, and I came up with basically this:

```
console.image = function(url, size = 100) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    var style = [
      'font-size: 1px;',
      'padding: ' + this.height/100*size + 'px ' + this.width/100*size + 'px;',
      'background: url('+ url +') no-repeat;',
      'background-size: contain;'
     ].join(' ');
     console.log('%c ', style);
  };
  image.src = url;
};
```

and then just use `console.image(URL[, size]);` to print out the image.
The URL needs to be a valid URL and the size is basically percentage, with `100` being the default value. It can get shrunk down if the value is lower than `100`, and expanded if the value is higher than `100`.

Answer (score 10):

It appears that Chrome removed support for background images in the console in Chrome 101 and Edge 101.

I don't believe it has ever worked in Firefox (at least it does not in Firefox 100).

By contrast, it still works in Safari 15.4.

I have been trying to find an article that explains why this functionality was removed from Chrome/Edge but so far haven't come across any.

Comment: It still works with data64, I guess pulling image from a url was seen as a vulnerability. I would also love to know why it happened.

Comment: Confirmed that works.

`const img = new Image();`
`img.onload = (): void => {`
`const c = document.createElement('canvas');`
`const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');`
`if (ctx) {`
`c.width = imageObject.width;`
`c.height = imageObject.height;`
`ctx.drawImage(imageObject, 0, 0);`
`const dataUri = c.toDataURL('image/png');`
`const style = '...background-image: url(' + dataUri + '});...';`
`console.log('%c ', style);`
`}`
`};`
`imageObject.src = urlOfImageFile;`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into [your console.image GitHub repository](https://github.com/adriancooney/console.image) as a matter of fact while looking into the same issue. Although the post is quite old, I [learned from the horse's mouth](https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/TanDFKEN9Kn) that it works in [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html). In fact, I tried [your plugin demo](http://adriancooney.ie/console.image/) in Canary and was able to see the spinning chicken. I still haven't found out why it suddenly stopped working in Chrome. The feature still works in Firebug for Firefox. The [console.log() documentation for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-write#styling-console-output-with-css) on this only showcases text-based styling.

I found one [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283936/stylized-console-logging) where they load the image first and then apply the styling using `console.log("%c....", "...");`. Unfortunately, that still didn't work in "standard" Chrome.

So, short answer, it looks like Canary for now supports images in the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me in 2024:

```
export function debugImage(imageData: ImageData) {
  if (!imageData) return
  if (!imageData.width || !imageData.height) return

  try {
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(imageData.width, imageData.height)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
      canvas.convertToBlob().then((blob) => {
        const reader = new FileReader()

        reader.onload = () => {
          const dataUri = reader.result
          console.warn("dataUri", { blob, dataUri })

          const uniqueId = new Date().getTime()
          const style = `font-size: 300px; background: url("${dataUri}#${uniqueId}") no-repeat; background-size: contain;`
          console.log("%c     ", style)
        }

        reader.onerror = (error) => {
          console.error("Error: ", error)
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
      })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a Web Worker, `document`, `Image`, and `Canvas` are not available. If the image is an `ImageData`, it can be printed to the console using `OffscreenCanvas`:

```js
function debugImage(imageData) {
  try {
    const c = new OffscreenCanvas(imageData.width, imageData.height);
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      c.convertToBlob().then((blob) => {
        const dataUri = new FileReaderSync().readAsDataURL(blob);
        const style = `font-size: 300px; background-image: url("${dataUri}"); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;`;
        console.log("%c     ", style);
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Tested with Chrome 108.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that both requests the image data and displays it without any canvas creation.

Works in chrome 120.0.6099.225

The code is mostly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42916772
, and 2 lines from an answer from the current thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74675430

```
console.image = (url) =>{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = function(){
            const style = `font-size: 300px; background-image: url("${this.result}"); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;`;
            console.log("%c     ", style);
        };
        fr.readAsDataURL(xhr.response); // async call
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in 2024 also!

```js
console.image = function(url, height = 100) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin='anonymous';
    image.onload = function() {
        // build a data url
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = height || image.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = canvas.height * image.naturalWidth / image.naturalHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        const style = [
            'font-size: 1px;',
            `padding: ${canvas.height}px ${canvas.width}px;`,
            `background: url(${dataUrl}) no-repeat;`,
            'background-size: contain;'
        ].join(' ');
        console.log('%c ', style);
    };
    image.src = url;
};
console.image('https://www.alleycat.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/FELV-cat.jpg');
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to convert https image to **base64**

You need at least 10 reputation to post images. I can upload gif , Can find gif show in https://github.com/zhaoolee/ChromeAppHeroes/blob/master/page/121-console-importer-2023-12-20.md

```
$i('axios');
$i('crypto-js');

axios.get('https://placekitten.com/200/300', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  .then((response) => {
    // Convert the ArrayBuffer to WordArray
    const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(response.data);
    // Convert the WordArray to a base64 string
    const base64String = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(wordArray);
    const imageUrl = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64String}`; // Assuming the image is a JPEG
    // Create a new image and assign the base64 string as the source
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      // Once the image is loaded, use its dimensions to set the console padding
      const style = [
        'font-size: 1px;',
        `padding: ${this.naturalHeight / 2}px ${this.naturalWidth / 2}px;`, // Divide by 2 because of the 1px font-size trick
        `background: url(${imageUrl}) no-repeat;`,
        'background-size: contain;'
      ].join(' ');
      console.log('%c ', style);
    };
    image.src = imageUrl;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error fetching or encoding the image:', error);
  });
```