# How to display local image to console?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local

I just noticed that `javascript with css` makes it possible **to display different styles in the developer console**. Of course, this also makes it possible to display images in the console.

*Since I can use this feature for my project very well, I wanted to try it directly. Without success.*

With the code below (which I have from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26286167) I can output images with a 'URL' (i.e. online images).

**But for local images this does not work with Safari so far.**

Does anyone know why it doesn't work with local images, while it does with URL's? And does anyone know a workaround to still be able to display local images in the console?

---

**Note**: Please open your **browser console** for the snippet below: (Or find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/7wbnsp9u/3/)

```js
(function(url) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    console.log('%c', [
      'font-size: 1px;',
      'line-height: ' + this.height + 'px;',
      'padding: ' + this.height * .5 + 'px ' + this.width * .5 + 'px;',
      'background-size: ' + this.width + 'px ' + this.height + 'px;',
      'background: url(' + url + ');'
    ].join(' '));
  };
  image.src = url;
})('http://www.personal.psu.edu/users//w/z/wzz5072/mini.jpg');
```

```html
> Please open your <b>developer console</b>.
```

This is what it looks like in safari:

[image: im]

This is working **fine**:`('http://www.personal.psu.edu/users//w/z/wzz5072/mini.jpg');`

... while this is **not**: `('mini.jpg');` = `(/Users/xy/project/mini.jpg)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: FYI your example does not work in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Current version is 69.0.3497.92. How/why are you still using 54? It was released in 2016

Answer (score 5):

Browsers do not allow local file access like this for security. You will need a webserver running on localhost for this to work as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Base64 encoded images.

[image]

```js
var º = "%c";
var consoleNormal     = "font-family: sans-serif";
var consoleBold       = "font-family: sans-serif;" +
                        "font-weight: bold";
var consoleCode       = "background: #EEEEF6;" +
                        "border: 1px solid #B2B0C1;" +
                        "border-radius: 7px;" +
                        "padding: 2px 8px 3px;" +
                        "color: #5F5F5F;" +
                        "line-height: 22px;" +
                        "box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(178,176,193,0.3)";
var consoleBackground = "background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBO" +
                        "Rw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQ" +
                        "VQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAA" +
                        "BJRU5ErkJggg==')";


console.info(º+"Example: Normal", consoleNormal);
console.info(º+"Example: Bold", consoleBold);
console.info(º+"Example: Code", consoleCode);
console.info(º+"Example: Background", consoleBackground);
```