# How to print a console message that would always show at the bottom?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious how various websites use the `console.log()` function to be always located at the bottom, just like Facebook and Discord. Once the console is opened, my function should follow any previous/new console messages and be shown underneeth them.

Comment: You have two distinct questions. You should limit it to one and post a separate question if needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stylized console logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283936/stylized-console-logging)

Comment: @Mushroomator Honestly, I'm curious about how it logging if user open the web browser's console.

Comment: Do you mean it should show at the bottom/start when the console is open or just log the message?

Comment: @Bella When the console is open, logging the message as follow.

Comment: Please be more spesific. You want the function to be always localised at the bottom?

Comment: @Bella Yes, the​ Function​ will​ be​ always​ localised​ to​ bottom as​ same​ as​ Facebook​ and​ Discord​ do.

Comment: If you write code with no errors... you could just print it on load and it'll *seem* like its printing when they open the console

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this would be to check when the window is resized. Since you can't check the console without resizing the page, it would work (this works with both horizontal and vertical dev tools).

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  console.log('You resized this window or accessed the console.');
});
```

This could also be triggered when the window is resized, meaning that it would be better to use `console.log()` than `alert()`.